# jenkins shell throws inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: ruby, shell, jenkins

I'm trying to deploy ruby from jenkins shell with command "cap production deploy", but it throws an error:

> deploy@10.105.27.132's password:(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
>   cap aborted!
>   SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@10.105.27.132: Inappropriate ioctl for device
>   Errno::ENOTTY: Inappropriate ioctl for device

If I perform the command manually from the terminal it executes without problem.
I have set up public keys so that I can execute the command without any need to enter password and also added deploy keys to project in GitLab.

As I searched for an answer I saw that in most cases the problem is with the deploy keys, but I have added it to the project and I can execute the command manually from the terminal, so the problem must be in Jenkins shell.
It seems that it probably uses some interpretation of the terminal and not the real thing.

Is there a way I can fix this, so I can execute the command from Jenkins shell?

Comment: It seems like there is no device bound to the connection cause it is a pure command without interaction. The only way should be public key.

Comment: @GeminiKeith But I have created public key in Jenkins sever and added that to the production server also. Or do you mean some other way?

Comment: Have you configured your ssh server correctly?Could you login to your server without a password?

Comment: @GeminiKeith Yes, If I do ssh user@myserveraddress then I connect and login to it without a password. That is the connection to the production server, do I need to have password less connection to the gitlab server too?

Comment: It's actually not work according to your post. Have you ever configured the global credentials for login to the SSH server with public key already?

Comment: @GeminiKeith Does the ssh-keygen generated public key counts? I think it does. I have created that on Jenkins server and uploaded that to the production server 10.105.27.132. And I can do ssh deploy@10.105.27.132 without entering any password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I logged in jenkins server as Jenkins user and created public key with him and uploaded that to the production server. After that everything worked. I didn't see anywhere that Jenkins has its own users and that I have to create the public key with that user.